# Prevent hung workers in ASP.NET when reading the posted data

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have an issue caused by an external factor which is causing my app pool to queue up requests and hang. The issue seems to be caused when the client making the HTTP request somehow loses its TCP layer connection to my server, whilst the server is trying to read all the data POST'd to it.

I am using an Asynchronous HTTP handler, and I am using the following code to read all the posted data:

```cs
string post_data = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

I believe what is happening is that "ReadToEnd()" is blocking my worker thread and when the TCP layer is lost the thread is stuck there trying to read indefinitely. How can I prevent this from happening?

I am currently coding in .NET 2.0 but I can use a newer framework if this is required.

Comment: From MSDN:
`ReadToEnd` assumes that the stream knows when it has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection, `ReadToEnd` might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end, and should be avoided.

This is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpRequest.InputStream will *synchronously* read the entire request, then it returns the Stream as one huge chunk.  You'll want something like this instead (requires .NET 4.5):

```
string body = await new StreamReader(request.GetBufferlessInputStream()).ReadToEndAsync();
```

GetBufferlessInputStream() won't read the entire request eagerly; it returns a Stream that reads the request on-demand.  Then ReadToEndAsync() will asynchronously read from this Stream without tying up a worker thread.

To create a .NET 4.5-style async handler, subclass the [HttpTaskAsyncHandler](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/scott/asynchronous-http-handlers-in-asp-net-4-5/) class.  See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/04/03/async-in-4-5-worth-the-await.aspx) for more information on async / await in .NET 4.5.  You must also [target .NET 4.5 in Web.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx) to get this functionality.

Comment: I figured this might be the approach, so I will read the links and approve the answer. Thanks.